# Retrieve a list of all imports from a java package with a certain criteria

Tags: java, import, package

Let's say I need to find all imports in my package java/src/package1 that matches org.myproject.runtine.

What is the fastest and easiest way to do this?

Comment: Statically or at runtime?

Comment: Statically is fine for this case.

Comment: `grep` works fine.

Comment: @Pablo so use grep for windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grep works fine and is short:

Open a bash and navigate to the source-directory.

```
find . -name \*.java -exec grep -h "import org.myproject.runtine" {} \; |sort -u
```

You have a bash-Shell with grep, sort etc. when you install git from

[Git for Windows-Downloadpage](https://git-scm.com/download/win)

With git-Bash you can open a bash in the right directoy from the context menu of explorer '*Git Bash Here*'.